# How to add Dynamic Scope variables to a for loop in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, variables

I want to create dynamic scope variables. Here is a sample for loop that I created

`for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
   $scope.'linkName'+i = 'Some value';
   // it should be like $scope.linkName1, $scope.linkName2, etc.
}`

The problem is that it doesn't allow for me to create it this way. Do you know the best way that I can use a for loop to loop through an array of variable names and assign that value to the scope variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

`$scope['linkName'+i] = 'Some value';`

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank you. You are really  saved my day.

Comment: how to render the value of the dynamic variable inside the template? it is not working for me . I tried to use like this   `$scope["variableName_" + i] = 1122;  {{"variableName_"+ $index}}`  ,  In rendered UI,  it showed variable name instead of value in it. UI-Result: `variableName_0  variableName_1`  ..etc